# change point detection of a cummulative distribution

Tags: r, linear-regression, cdf

I have a cummulative rainfall time series and I would like to detect the change points. Here's the data.

```
structure(list(DAY = 1:365, CUMSUM = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3.8, 6.9, 6.9, 6.9, 
6.9, 6.9, 6.9, 6.9, 6.9, 6.9, 6.9, 6.9, 6.9, 6.9, 6.9, 6.9, 7.4, 
7.4, 7.4, 7.4, 7.4, 7.4, 7.4, 7.4, 7.4, 7.4, 7.4, 7.4, 7.4, 22.6, 
22.6, 22.6, 22.6, 22.6, 22.6, 22.8, 26.7, 41.3, 41.3, 44.7, 44.7, 
44.7, 86.8, 92.6, 92.6, 115.2, 117, 126, 134.9, 134.9, 134.9, 
140.7, 140.7, 140.7, 146.5, 146.7, 146.7, 151.7, 152.7, 196.5, 
242.7, 293.4, 331.4, 340, 345.6, 369.5, 442.6, 459, 464.6, 464.6, 
468.2, 475.6, 484.2, 487.8, 487.8, 511, 515, 515, 515, 528.8, 
547.6, 549.4, 549.8, 550, 552.4, 585.9, 798.5, 1062.5, 1107.9, 
1124.5, 1154, 1169.4, 1416.4, 1457.6, 1457.6, 1457.6, 1461.2, 
1464, 1524.7, 1539.5, 1552, 1592.8, 1599.4, 1608.6, 1611.6, 1616.2, 
1656.6, 1667.6, 1667.6, 1668.8, 1680, 1687.1, 1697.9, 1704.7, 
1726.6, 1726.6, 1727.6, 1732.6, 1750.2, 1834.4, 1882.2, 1915.6, 
1940, 1976.6, 2001.2, 2026.4, 2042.6, 2078.1, 2101.2, 2109.2, 
2109.2, 2109.2, 2109.2, 2117, 2117, 2120.2, 2142.4, 2153.4, 2173.4, 
2174.4, 2174.4, 2174.4, 2178.4, 2213.5, 2365.1, 2449.7, 2565.5, 
2673.7, 2749.9, 2830.3, 2896.2, 2920.8, 3236.4, 3266.8, 3288.9, 
3371.5, 3428.5, 3642.5, 3764.9, 3774.9, 3818.7, 3818.7, 3830.9, 
3953.7, 4127.8, 4206, 4217.7, 4217.7, 4219.9, 4220.9, 4220.9, 
4361.1, 4378, 4378, 4388.4, 4393.4, 4417.3, 4419.9, 4419.9, 4419.9, 
4470.3, 4480.3, 4480.7, 4490.7, 4492.9, 4493.4, 4504, 4504, 4504, 
4505.4, 4509.8, 4509.8, 4509.8, 4509.8, 4509.8, 4509.8, 4509.8, 
4510.4, 4510.4, 4512.8, 4515.4, 4517.8, 4527.5, 4532.1, 4539.7, 
4541.7, 4573.3, 4606.5, 4607.3, 4613.5, 4613.5, 4613.5, 4613.5, 
4613.5, 4613.5, 4613.5, 4613.5, 4613.5, 4613.5, 4613.9, 4621.1, 
4621.1, 4621.1, 4636.5, 4647.9, 4649.1, 4649.3, 4649.3, 4649.3, 
4655, 4655, 4663.6, 4663.6, 4664.2, 4664.2, 4665, 4665, 4665, 
4665, 4665, 4665, 4665, 4665, 4665, 4665, 4665, 4665, 4665, 4665, 
4665.9, 4665.9, 4665.9, 4665.9, 4665.9, 4665.9, 4665.9, 4665.9, 
4665.9, 4665.9, 4665.9, 4665.9, 4665.9, 4673.1, 4673.1, 4673.1, 
4673.1, 4673.1, 4673.1, 4673.1, 4673.1, 4673.1, 4673.5, 4673.5, 
4673.5, 4673.5, 4673.5, 4673.5, 4673.5, 4673.5, 4673.5)), .Names = 
c("DAY","CUMSUM"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -365L))
```

I would like to apply a **two phase linear regression** in detecting the change points here using R.

There is a matlab code available here 
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26804-two-phase-linear-regression-model

but there is no equivalent package in R.

Can anyone suggest how to do this?

Here's the expected output.
[image: Expected output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the R package `segmented`; here is a step-by-step example.

1. Load the library.

   ```
   library(segmented);
   ```
2. Fit a piecewise linear model with two breakpoints to the sample data (here I assume `df` contains the data as a `data.frame`). Note that we must provide some guesses for the breakpoints.

   ```
   fit <- lm(CUMSUM ~ DAY, data = df);
   fit.seg <- segmented(fit, psi = c(100, 200));
   fit.seg;
   #Call: segmented.lm(obj = fit, psi = c(100, 200))
   #
   #Meaningful coefficients of the linear terms:
   #(Intercept)          DAY       U1.DAY       U2.DAY
   #     -58.20         1.25        35.70       -34.98
   #
   #Estimated Break-Point(s):
   #psi1.DAY  psi2.DAY
   #   153.8     272.9
   ```
3. We plot the curve and mark the breakpoint estimates in red.

   ```
   library(ggplot2);
   ggplot(df, aes(DAY, CUMSUM)) +
       geom_line() +
       geom_vline(data = as.data.frame(fit.seg$psi), aes(xintercept = `Est.`), col = "red")
   ```

[image]

4. More details can be found in the `segmented` [reference manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/segmented/segmented.pdf) on CRAN. The return object `fit.seg` also contains parameter estimates for each piece.

Comment: @Mauits Evers. When I changed the lm() formula to CUMSUM~1, this gives the following error: `Error in all.vars(seg.Z) : argument "seg.Z" is missing, with no default`. Is this only applicable for CUMSUM~DAY?

Comment: @Lyndz It's all explained quite well in the reference manual; if you take a look at `?segmented` you see that `seg.Z` refers to the continuous covariate(s) that have a piecewise-linear relationship with the response. If there is only *one* covariate, `seg.Z` may be omitted. A linear model *without* any covariate such as `CUMSUM ~ 1` (so only with an offset) does not work. From a statistical modelling point of view, such a model also makes no sense for the data you give. There exists other methods to fit piecewise constant functions, but that is different from "two-phase linear models".

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but a comment (too long to be edited in the comments sections).

I find your numerical example interesting, especially to be compared to the results obtained thanks to the method from the paper : https://fr.scribd.com/document/380941024/Regression-par-morceaux-Piecewise-Regression-pdf

The algorithm given pages 30-31 is not iterative and doesn't require initial guess. The result is shown on the first figure below :

[image]

The fitted piecewise function is made of three linear segments. But the first and third segments are not exactly horizontal as requested in your question.

In fact, this comes from the fitting of an integral equation as mentioned in the referenced paper. To get horizontal first and third segments, the calculus has to be simplified with the parameters p1=p3=0. Moreover, the parameters q1=0 and q3=4673.5 are a-priori known. The algorithm is simplified :

[image]

The result is :

[image]

The results are slightly different from those of the R package : a1=153.8 and a2=272.9

It is interesting to observe that the closest results are with the assumption of not exactly horizontal first and third segments (a1=152 and a2=274).

Of course, it is not surprising to obtain slightly different results because, in each case, the criterion for the regression are not the same (and we don't know exactly what they are in the R-package).

Answer (score 0):

We could treat the problem in a different perspective.

By diffing the data, we have the plot: [plot of diff'd data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsQdj.png).

We can use a simple mean change model:

```r
> fastcpd::fastcpd.mean(diff(data))
                                                                                                                                      
A fastcpd object.
Available methods to evaluate the object are:
plot, print, show, summary


Change points:
[1] 173 242
```

Alternatively, an AR(1) model can be fitted here as well:

```r
> suppressMessages(fastcpd::fastcpd.ar(diff(data), 1))
                                                                                                                                      
A fastcpd object.
Available methods to evaluate the object are:
plot, print, show, summary


Change points:
[1] 173 236
```

Disclaimer: I am the developer of the R package `fastcpd`.